# AWS CodeBuild throws an error "CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching artifact paths found

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-codebuild

AWS CodeBuild throws an error "CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching artifact paths found".

I'm trying to build a docker app using CodeCommit repository, Build phase seems to be passing without problems, but there is some issue with the artifact file path.

This is the link, I have referred https://youtu.be/MDMH_XXDbrI
Timestamp: 48:18 to 56:24

Here is my buildspec:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
      - REPOSITORY_URI=$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}
    build:
     commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...          
      - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
      - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG    
     post_build:
      commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
      - echo Writing image definitions file...
      - printf '[{"name":"%s","imageUri":"%s"}]' "$IMAGE_REPO_NAME" "$REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG" > imagedefinitions.json
artifacts:
  files: imagedefinitions.json
```

Here is the build log:

```
[Container] 2023/05/06 06:40:30 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2023/05/06 06:40:30 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2023/05/06 06:40:30 Entering phase BUILD
[Container] 2023/05/06 06:40:30 Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2023/05/06 06:40:30 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2023/05/06 06:40:30 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2023/05/06 06:40:30 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2023/05/06 06:40:30 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2023/05/06 06:40:30 Expanding base directory path: .
[Container] 2023/05/06 06:40:30 Assembling file list
[Container] 2023/05/06 06:40:30 Expanding .
[Container] 2023/05/06 06:40:30 Expanding file paths for base directory .
[Container] 2023/05/06 06:40:30 Assembling file list
[Container] 2023/05/06 06:40:30 Expanding imagedefinitions.json
[Container] 2023/05/06 06:40:30 Skipping invalid file path imagedefinitions.json
[Container] 2023/05/06 06:40:30 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/05/06 06:40:30 Phase context status code: CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching artifact paths found
```

I don't have a clue what is wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in the last line of the buildspec.yml file.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
      - REPOSITORY_URI=$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...          
      - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
      - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG    
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
      - echo Writing image definitions file...
      - printf '[{"name":"%s","imageUri":"%s"}]' "$IMAGE_REPO_NAME" "$REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG" > imagedefinitions.json
artifacts:
    files: 
      - 'imagedefinitions.json'
```

And the Build was successful